# json item display issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I cannot get some of my json items displayed, in particular all **custom_fields** items.
Please find below my json and jquery code.

========== JSON ==============

```
 {
  "status": "ok",
  "count": 1,
  "count_total": 1,
  "pages": 1,
  "posts": [
   {
  {
  "id": 89,
  "type": "events",
  "slug": "%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8c%d0%b5",
  "url": "https:\/\/domain.com\/events\/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8c%d0%b5\/",
  "status": "publish",
  "title": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0434\u044c\u0435",
  "title_plain": "\u041f\u043e\u043b\u043e\u0432\u043e\u0434\u044c\u0435",
  "content": "<p>\u0424\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043b\u044c \u043c\u0443\u0437\u044b\u043a\u0438 \u0438 \u043c\u043e\u0434\u044b<\/p>\n",
  "excerpt": "\u0424\u0435\u0441\u0442\u0438\u0432\u0430\u043b\u044c \u043c\u0443\u0437\u044b\u043a\u0438 \u0438 \u043c\u043e\u0434\u044b",
  "date": "2013-06-25 09:26:49",
  "modified": "2013-06-26 10:18:13",
  "categories": [],
  "tags": [],
  "author": {
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "vzakharov",
    "name": "vzakharov",
    "first_name": "",
    "last_name": "",
    "nickname": "vzakharov",
    "url": "",
    "description": ""
  },
  "comments": [],
  "attachments": [],
  "comment_count": 0,
  "comment_status": "closed",
  "custom_fields": {
    "wpcf-event-date": [
      "1373130000"
    ],
    "wpcf-venue": [
      "\u041f\u043b\u043e\u0449\u0430\u0434\u044c \u043d\u0430\u0440\u043e\u0434\u043d\u044b\u0445 \u0433\u0443\u043b\u044f\u043d\u0438\u0439"
    ]
  }
}
  ]
 }
```

============= JQUERY =================

```
 $(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'link_to_json',
    async: false,
    callback: 'callback',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data, status) {
        if (data !== undefined && data.posts !== undefined) {

            $.each(data.posts, function (i, item) {
                $('#dayevent').append('<span>' + item.title + item.custom_fields[0].wpcf-venue + item.custom_fields[0].wpcf-event-date +'</span>');
            });
        }

    },
    error: function () {
        $('#news').append('No connection.');
    }
});
});
```

And show timpestamp of **wpcf-event-date** as a normal date. Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because your `custom_fields` property is an `Object`, not an array.  This means that your index `custom_fields[0]` isn't going to work as you intend.  To get the proper value out of your custom_fields object you have to index it with your key, which in this case is `wpcf-venue`

```
item.custom_fields['wpcf-event-date']; // "1373130000"
```

See my jsfiddle if you're still confused.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8hU2/1/)

EDIT: with regards to showing `wpcf-event-date` as a normal date, you can use date libraries such as [momentjs](http://momentjs.org) which I would recommend, or do something similar to this:

```
Date d = new Date(1373130000 * 1000);
```

Where 1373130000 is your unix timestamp.

Comment: Thank you Braden. I have downloaded momentjs but don't know how to display timestamp in correct format from json, can you please show me in you jsfiddle please?

Comment: moment(myobj.custom_fields['wpcf-event-date'] * 1000)  Should work, but I haven't tried it in a fiddle

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. json appears in moment(1373130000 * 1000) but date isn't showing at all. ;-( Am very desperate. Please help...

Comment: Okay, if you do `var d = moment(1373130000 * 1000);`  You then have a moment object which represents date and can call things like `d.years()` or `d.months()`, or even `d.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');` which results in something like `"July 6th 2013, 10:00:00 am"`